# ServiceControl doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

I have ServiceControl setup on it's own VM and configured to use SQL Transport which I have pointed at the SQL database that's currently being used for NServiceBus. I've opened up port 33333 in the firewall on both the VM and in Azure NSG. I also installed OpenSSH and opened those ports.

On my local machine, I've opened a tunnel to the ServiceControl VM and forwarded port 33333. The tunnel opens without issue. I am running ServiceInsight on my local machine and have it connect to localhost:33333 which is forwarded to the remote VM. It connects without any reported error.

That's it. There is no data displayed in ServiceInsight. No endpoints in the endpoint explorer or anything.

Did I miss something? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Did you setup your endpoints to forward audit messages to SC? Did you install the heartbeat plugin? more info here: https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/

Comment: There is a followup discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/particularsoftware/Nlf9o_8OMlU